# Geometric quotient of $\mathbb{A}^2$ modulo $G$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, group-actions, zariski-topology

I have the following exercise:
***(This exercise deals with the action of a group $G$ on an affine closed.)***

---

*Let $G=\langle w \rangle$ be a cyclic group of order $n$ (in multiplicative notation).
Consider the action of $G$ on $\mathbb{A}^2$ defined by $$w(x,y):=(wx,w^{-1}y)$$
Prove that the geometric quotient $\mathbb{A}^2/ G$ is isomorphic to the closed affine set $Z(uv-w^n)\subset \mathbb{A}^3$*

---

I thought about proceeding this way.

I know that a geometric quotient $Y=\mathbb{A}^2/ G$ is such that
$$K[Y]=K[\mathbb{A}^2]^G \hookrightarrow^{\psi^*}  K[\mathbb{A}^2]$$
where:

- $K[Y]$ is the set of regular functions on $Y$,
- $K[\mathbb{A}^2]^G=\{f\in K[\mathbb{A}^2]: f=f^g \; \forall g \in
     G\}$ is the set of regular functions on $\mathbb{A}^2$ which are
  $G$-invariant
- $\psi^*:  K[Y] \hookrightarrow  K[\mathbb{A}^2]$ is
  such that for the corresponding $\psi: \mathbb{A}^2 \rightarrow Y$
  the following property holds  $$\psi(p)=\psi(q) \iff \;\;  p \;
     \textit{and}\; q \;\textit{are in the same orbit of G}$$

So, I'd like to try to figure out who $Y$ is.

I have examined the orbits of $G$ studying the equivalence classes by means of the relation
$$p,q \in \mathbb{A}^2, \;\;\;\; p \sim q \iff \exists g \in G: q=p^g$$
in this case, because $G=\langle w\rangle$ of order $n$
$$(x,y),(a,b) \in \mathbb{A}^2 \;\;\; (x,y)\sim (a,b) \iff \exists t\le n : (a,b)=(w^tx,w^{-t}y)$$
so there are four possibilities

1. $a=x=b=y=0$ i.e the origin $\{0\}$
2. $a=x=0, b,y\neq0$ i.e the $x$ axis
3. $b=y=0, a,x\neq0$ i.e the $y$ axis
4. $a,x,b,y\neq0$ i.e $\mathbb{A}^2 \setminus \{0\}$

**These are the orbits of G, aren't they?**

Now, can I assert that Y is made up of these four classes?
I believe so because we are in a finite group and therefore the set quotient (and not geometric quotient) has a natural geometric structure and therefore $\psi$ coincides with the application of the set quotient.

**Is everything said so far correct?**

If everything is correct, then how can I find an isomorphism with $Z(uv-w^n)\subset \mathbb{A}^3$?
I can't picture this closed up in my mind. Could someone explain me better?

Why if $w$ generates $G$ of order $n$ we take $w ^ n$? Isn't it unity?
If it is the unit, then the origin $(0,0)$ and the points on the axes $(x, 0)$ and $(0, y)$ [which according to my idea are in the quotient $Y$] would not cancel the polynomial $uv-1$ and therefore they would not be in closed $Z(uv-w^n)$.
Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$K[x,y]^G = \{ \sum_{a,b,\ n\ |\ a-b} c_{a,b} x^ay^b\}= K[x^n,y^n,xy]\cong K[u,v,w]/(w^n-uv)$$
The isomorphism is $G.(x,y)\to (x^n,y^n,xy)$

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand some things: 
$$ $$
1. Why is this equality true
$$\biggl\{\sum_{a,b,n|a−b} c_{a,b}x^ay^b\biggr\}=K[x^n,y^n,xy]$$


2. Who are the domain and codomion of the shown isomorphism? $Y$ and $Z(uv−w^n)$ or $K[x,y]^G$ and $K[u,v,w]/(w^n−uv)$? 


$$ $$
3. In your reasoning, who is $Y$? Was it not right my idea that, being $G$ a finite group, geometric quotient and set quotient coincided and therefore $Y$ was composed of those 4 equivalence classes found?

Comment: Once these things are cleared up, given your steps, I would proceed like this 
$$K[x,y]/I(Y) \simeq K[Y]=K[x,y]^G \simeq K[u,v,w]/(w^n−uv)$$
so $I(Y)\simeq (w^n−uv)$ and $Y=Z(I(Y))\simeq Z(w^n−uv)$.
$$ $$
It's correct?

Comment: $Y$ is implicit. We are quotienting $\Bbb{A}^2$ as a set, but this doesn't give $\Bbb{A}^2/G$ the structure of a variety. To do so we think to $G$ as acting on the coordinate ring, we do the quotient of the coordinate ring, obtaining a finitely generated $K$-algebra, which is (isomorphic to) the coordinate of an affine variety (which is $Y=V(w^n-uv)$). Then the obtained isomorphism $K[\Bbb{A}^2]^G\to K[Y]$ corresponds to a set wise bijection $\Bbb{A}^2/G\to Y$ (given by $G.(x,y)\to (x^n,y^n,xy)$). This way any quotient $X/G$ of a variety by a finite group  has a variety structure

Comment: So there is no such thing as $K[x,y]/I(Y)$, you are searching for the wrong thing, all you have is what I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Sorry I meant we pick the subring of $K[\Bbb{A^2}]$ invariant under the action of $G$, not a quotient of $K[\Bbb{A}^2]$.

Comment: Sorry, but $\mathbb{A}^2/G$  and $Y$  are varieties, aren't they? So the isomorphism between them is meant in the sense of variety (i.e. as a biregular application), right?
$$ $$
So, without going through $K[\mathbb{A}^2/G]$ and $K[Y]$, could I directly prove that this
$$\begin{aligned} \mathbb{A}^2/G &\rightarrow Y \\ (x,y) &\mapsto (x^n,y^n,xy) \end{aligned}$$
 is a biregular application?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116455/discussion-between-pina-merenda-and-reuns).

Comment: @PinaMerenda Not quite that's what I'm explaining : $\Bbb{A}^2/G$ is a set, it becomes a variety only when we attach to it a 'coordinate ring' $K[\Bbb{A}^2]^G$. This ring is $\cong K[u,v,w]/(w^n-uv)$ and it **is by definition** that **as a variety** $\Bbb{A}^2/G\cong V(w^n-uv)$. Try with $\Bbb{C}/\pm 1$, your 'biregular map' is $\pm z\to z^2$ whose inverse is $z\to\pm z^{1/2}$, not quite given by a regular function.

Comment: $\Bbb{A^2/G}$ is a variety only once we say that by definition it is isomorphic to $Y=V(w^n-uv)$.